# How to put a complicated dictionary into a table using python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a dictionary that contains 3 key (ffa, lingual and ppa), when within each of these keys is another dictionary that contains  another 5 keys which are the 5 participants, attached to each key is a tuple of 2 numbers which are the mean and SD for that participants. Because I have pulled the data from text files I do not have raw data in the script because it needs to be adaptable for other text files.

so when i try to put this dictionary into a table, my means and SD stay in one column (both under the mean).

```
ROI            COPE        MEAN                  SD
ffa          cope1      (0.6525, 0.0)
ffa          cope2      (0.4146, 0.0)
ffa          cope3      (0.5896, 0.0)
ffa          cope4      (0.1521, 0.0)
ffa          cope5      (0.5317, 0.0)
lingual      cope1      (-0.08865060000000001, 0.18218909587360052)
lingual      cope2      (-0.150985, 0.19045722970000376)
lingual      cope3      (-0.162005, 0.156594265045052)
lingual      cope4      (-0.130845, 0.1723191040627823)
lingual      cope5      (-0.126411, 0.1327233022080147)
ppa          cope1      (0.74836, 0.46169785834461047)
ppa          cope2      (0.9444, 0.43539771473906475)
ppa          cope3      (0.300482, 0.25656049991376306)
ppa          cope4      (1.12435, 0.40710618332322096)
ppa          cope5      (0.8332200000000001, 0.5046582384148702)
```

however i want them to be in separate columns, the means under the mean heading and the SD's under the SD heading like this-

```
ROI            COPE        MEAN                  SD
ffa            cope1      0.6525                 0.0
ffa            cope2      0.4146                 0.0
ffa            cope3      0.5896                 0.0
ffa            cope4      0.1521                 0.0
ffa            cope5      0.5317                 0.0
lingual        cope1      -0.08865060000000001   0.18218909587360052
lingual        cope2      -0.150985              0.19045722970000376
lingual        cope3      -0.162005              0.156594265045052
lingual        cope4      -0.130845              0.1723191040627823
ect....
```

this is the code used to create the dictionary

```
Results = {"ffam": {}, "lingualm": {}, "ppam": {}}
for k in ffaResults:
    Results["ffam"][k] = statistics.mean(ffaResults[k]),statistics.pstdev(ffaResults[k])
for k in lingualResults:
    Results["lingualm"][k] = statistics.mean(lingualResults[k]), statistics.pstdev(lingualResults[k])
for k in ppaResults:
    Results["ppam"][k] = statistics.mean(ppaResults[k]), statistics.pstdev(ppaResults[k])
```

and this is the code i have for the table

```
data = [(k,*x)  for k, v in Results.items() for x in v.items()]
print ("ROI            COPE        MEAN                  SD")
for l in data:
        print ("{:<14}{:<11}{}".format(l[0],l[1],l[2]))
```

Is there a way to do this in the dictionary?

Comment: in your (somehow convoluted) code, `Results["ppam"][k]` stores a `(mean, sd)` tuple. You have to either store those values under different keys when building `Results`, or unpack them when printing your data.

Comment: Thank you, yes I realise it is quite complicated. Could you please suggest how to unpack them when printing the data?